# PHP checkbox return value (checked/not checked) and update

Tags: php, select, checkbox, sql-update

I have a form that submits a load of checkboxes - This works fine.

I then have a form i can open which will display said checkboxes and will be checked or not checked based on the SQL query ran.

SQL query runs ok with echo but I cannot get the box to show as checked. After this I want to be able to check uncheck the boxes and update via an SQL.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);
    $data = $_GET['id'];
    require 'connect.php';
    $sql1 = "SELECT id, phone, email, pager
    FROM [dbo].[preference] WHERE id = '$data'";
    $stmt1 = sqlsrv_query($con,$sql1);
    if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(),true));
}   
        while ($row1 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt1)){
        $id = $row1['id'];
        $phone = $row1['phone'];
        $email = $row1['email'];
        $pager = $row1['pager'];
}
?>


<td><input type="checkbox" name="phone" class="check" value="1">phone</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="email" class="check" value="1">email</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="pager" class="check" value="1">pager</td>
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Not sure I follow your question. You need to echo `checked` on the inputs based off current value? Or you don't get how to perform the update?

Comment: Thanks for coming back. echo checked or not checked based on value returned from sql however need to be able to change the value while the form is loaded and update. the update part will be straight forward. Just not sure how i display loaded value then be able to change it

Comment: In `while loop` you are setting `$phone` two time. first line store id in $phone and second line store phone in $phone.

Comment: Sorry i have amended to id

Comment: **You have a SQL injection security vulnerability** in this code. Do not put this on the internet if you value your security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not really sure I understand the question...

You load the script after an update. The rendering reflects the current state at that time. You submit to the script, perform the update, then reload... which then renders that updated state...

```
<?php
        ...
        $id = $row1['id'];
        $phone = $row1['phone'];
        $email = $row1['email'];
        $pager = $row1['pager'];
}
?>


<td><input type="checkbox" name="phone" class="check" value="1" <?= (!empty($phone)) ? 'CHECKED' : '' ?>>phone</td>
...
```

High level...

```
//pseudo code for a CRUD script...

//is this a POST?
if (isset($_POST['submit')) {
  //validate user input, never trust the user, beware SQL injection...

  //if passes validation update the values in the database

  //if not, raise error flags, re-display the form (you'll see you need to use the supplied POST data, that failed to validate, as the inputs values or you'll lose the provided input, think it will make sense when you het here...)
}

//here could be a POST or initial load... could even flow here to provide confirmation of update and show new values

//load current data from database

//render form based off vurrent values
```

Comment: Thats right, loads from data previously submitted showing if they were checked or not on the prior forms submission then need to be able to change.

Comment: This seems to be working for the get value thanks. I this amendable so that if i uncheck now and submit it would take the value as not checked? sorry not too great at explaining myself

Comment: Try it and see... sounds sort of like you are confused by the nature of HTTP... stateless / stateful? I'm not explaining well either. I'll expand the answer a bit...

Comment: Just used it as the update it works a charm. Thank you so much. 1 line of code has consumed almost 14 hours of my time.

Comment: Where i was going wrong is i was just trying to echo the value inside value="" and wondering how i would get its current state.. Looking back its an amatuer mistake haha thanks again! :)

Comment: right... forms as an object, incorporating validation, is something you'll see in most frameworks. That and `data objects` / `entities` Helps a lot with this... Might want to explore how form CRUD is handled in a modern PHP framework. Anyway, glad you are making progress!

Answer (score 0):

like let say in $phone the value is either 'checked'

your code should be

`<td><input type="checkbox" name="phone" class="check" value="1" <?php ($phone == 'checked' ? 'checked' : '') ?>>phone</td>`

Comment: Thanks just trying this now. Would the values in the tables have to be "checked" as i currently have 1 and 0

Comment: its fine if you used 1 or 0. 1 mean checked and 0 mean not checked.